# Why is fence status checking and resetting in Vulkan so slow?

Tags: vulkan

If I check the status of a fence with vkGetFenceStatus() it takes about 0.002 milliseconds. This may not seem like a long time, but that amount of time in a rendering or game engine is a very long time, especially when waiting on fences while doing other scheduled jobs will soon add up to time quickly approaching a millisecond. If the fence statuses are kept host-side why does it take so long to check these and reset them? Do other people get similar timings when calling this function?

Comment: "*especially when waiting on fences while doing other scheduled jobs will soon add up to time quickly approaching a millisecond*" Why would you be doing it more than a couple of times per-frame?

Comment: @NicolBolas Well to be honest I don't know how many times I'll be doing it, I guess it depends on how long it takes. How long should the jobs take?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ideally, the time it takes to check for a fence being set shouldn't matter. While taking up 0.02% of a frame at 120FPS isn't ideal, at the end of the day, it should not be all that important. The ideal scenario works like this:

Basically, you should build your fence logic around the idea that you're only going to check the fence if it's almost certainly already set.

If you submit frame 1, you should not check the fence when you're starting to build frame 2. You should only check it when you're starting to build frame 3 (or 4, depending on how much delay you're willing to tolerate).

And most importantly, if it isn't set, that should represent a case where either the CPU isn't doing enough work or the GPU has been given too much work. If the CPU is outrunning the GPU, it's fine for the CPU to wait. That is, the CPU performance no longer matters, since you're GPU-bound.

So the time it takes to check the fence is more or less irrelevant.

If you're in a scenario where you're task dispatching and you want to run the graphics task ASAP, but you have other tasks available if the graphics task isn't ready yet, that's where this may become a problem. But even so, it would only be a problem for that small space of time between the first check to see if the graphics task is ready and the point where you've run out of other tasks to start and the CPU needs to start waiting on the GPU to be ready.

In that scenario, I would suggest testing the fence only twice per frame. Test it at the first opportunity; if its not set, do *all* of the other tasks you can. After those tasks are dispatched/done... just wait on the GPU with `vkWaitForFences`. Either the fence is set and the function will return immediately, or you're waiting for the GPU to be ready for more data.

There are other scenarios where this could be a problem. If the GPU lacks dedicated transfer queues, you may be testing the same fence for different purposes. But even in those cases, I would suggest only testing the fence once per frame. If the data upload isn't done, you either have to do a hard sync if that data is essential right now, or you delay using it until the next frame.

---

If this remains a concern, and your Vulkan implementation allows timeline semaphores, consider using them to keep track of queue progress. `vkGetSemaphoreCounterValue` may be faster than `vkGetFenceStatus`, since it's just reading a number.